# Column added to pandas dataframe doesn't stick when eg. writing to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a seemingly simple situation: I'm working with a dataframe and am adding columns that are calculated based on existing columns in the dataframe. At the last line in the snippet below, python complains that the 'reg_per' column isn't found. Even if I do not specify what columns to write, python will only write the original, non-calculated, columns to the csv file. If I add `print data.reg_per` just before the last line below, it works as I would expect (ie. python finds the added column). How do I make this work?

`slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(data.tendex, data.PER)
reg_per = intercept + slope * data.tendex
data.reg_per = pd.Series(reg_per, index = data.index)
data.to_csv('tendex_vs_per_reg.csv', columns = ['reg_per'])`

Comment: Can you try this `data['reg_per'] = pd.Series(reg_per, index = data.index)` what you're doing is adding an attribute rather than a column

Comment: Also, you can just assign `reg_per` directly, no need to build a series from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
data.reg_per = pd.Series(reg_per, index = data.index)
```

You are just setting the property, not writing a column

```
data['reg_per'] = pd.Series(reg_per, index = data.index)
```

Avoid the . accessor, as it leads to errors like this one.

Comment: Brilliant - that works perfectly (would upvote, but I don't have enough reputation...)

Comment: Actually the only thing you are *supposed* to do is click the arrow to mark the question as solved. This requires no reputation ;)